# What is causing Apache to segfault while setting a cookie of 276 chars in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I'm setting a cookie in PHP, like this:

```
setcookie('searchParameters', '{"cordationages":"BY,BE,BO,BR,CA,DK,DO,FI,FR,DE,GR,IS,IN,IE,IT,JP,MT,MX,MN,NL,NZ,NO,PL,RO,RU,ES,CH","santarila":"ANY","frexin":"d","minimumCar":"98","maximumCar":"XD","requireDolprin":"NO","requireHousemath":"YES","maxinabilityFring":"PRIN-KOSLL","maxinabilityFor":"PRAZ-KO-LL"}', $expiry);
```

Which is causing the following segmentation fault in Apache:

```
[core:notice] [pid 42457] AH00052: child pid 45486 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

The strange thing is that if I shorten the cookie string by 3 characters (by, say, removing any of the country codes from the comma-delineated list) it works just fine.

As far as I'm aware the limit for cookie length is far longer than this. Does anyone have any theories as to what is going on?

I'm on MacOS 10.14.6
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 22 2019 20:20:11

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the length of that value should not be a problem at all. Does the same thing happen, if you don’t try to set a JSON value, but just something like `AAAAA…` of the same length? Does using `setrawcookie` instead make any difference?

Comment: Interesting find @CBroe. So: setting straight letters like you suggested does NOT cause a segfault. But isn't this just...text? There are no special or strange characters in the string. Do PHP or Apache even know that it's JSON? Also, setrawcookie gives me the error: :  "Cookie values cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' "

Comment: Any security modules / extensions running perhaps, that could have an interest in what gets put into cookies?

Comment: I'm afraid not... The only extension I really have is mod_rewrite, but nothing fancy going on there. Is there a way to get better error messages from Apache perhaps?